# Golang net/http/httptest error crypto/x509.unknownauthorityerror

Tags: go

I am trying to mock out a response from a HTTPS web service responding to my Golang package.

In my unit test I am using net/http/httptest.

My function is

```
ts := httptest.NewTLSServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
fmt.Fprintln(w, "hello")
}))

defer ts.Close()

tr := &http.Transport{TLSClientConfig: &TLS.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}}
client := ts.Client()
client= &http.Client{Transport:tr}
res, err := client.Get(ts.URL)
```

When I step through the code and my package makes the call to the mock service, it errors with error (crypto/x509.UnknownAuthorityError)

I thought the skip verify is meant ignore verifying any certificates? Yes, I am mocking out certificates when my package is instantiated, but for the purpose of the test, I am not interested in the certificates all I want to do is verify the response coming back and the code after.

What am I doing wrong with mocking a HTTPS request response?

Comment: Use the tls config created by your test server

Comment: Please explain?

Comment: The [test server](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httptest#Server) has all the information needed to connect. Just like the URL field, there is a TLS field which says it is “populated with a new config after TLS is started”